# Creating a user who cannot get an interactive shell

Tags: shell, users

What are interactive and non-interactive shell?

Questions: Create a user john who should not get an interactive shell.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 11):

The `/etc/passwd` file has as the last item on a user's line the program to be run upon login.  For normal users this is typically set to `/bin/sh` or other shell (e.g. bash, zsh).

Traditionally, identities that are used to own processes or files or other resources have their "shell" set to `/bin/false` as in

```
syslog:x:101:102::/home/syslog:/bin/false
```

The pseudo-user syslog owns `/var/log/syslog` and is the only UID which has write permission for that file, but one cannot log in as user syslog as there is no command interpreter to be run.

Answer (score 10):

Regarding the question you are trying to answer:

> Create a user john who should not get an interactive shell.

The question means "Create a user named `john` who won't be able to log in and run commands from a shell". Interactive describe the way the shell works: the user types something, and the shell does something accordingly (there is a kind of communication between the user and the shell). The word "interactive" doesn't really add any information to the question, because as long as there is a user typing commands, the shell session is interactive.

There is also the non-interactive mode, where the user saves a series of commands they want to run in a file (called a shell script), and executes the file afterwards. Some commands behave differently depending on whether the shell is run interactively or non-interactively. You can read more [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html) (this document is for `bash`, but the same concept applies for other shells).

On how to create such a user, if you skim through `man useradd` there is an option to set the login shell, `-s` or `--shell`. You can also create a user normally, in anyway you want (which I assume you know already?), then edit `/etc/passwd` like in [msw's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4676/interactive-shell-vs-non-interactive-shell/4678#4678).

Comment: The way I understand it, Interactive log in is using a keyboard and monitor directly connected to the machine, and the opposite is being remotely, and specifically over the network, using some service like `ssh`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,  change the shell in the password file (/etc/passwd) to some program that will **not** not allow a shell escape.

if you want to be a [bofh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastard_Operator_From_Hell) /bin/false will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
adduser username -s /sbin/nologin
```

Comment: Notice the username is specified in the question as "john".  Wouldn't hurt to use a little prose to explain what your command is doing and why it fulfills the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
adduser john -s /sbin/nologin
```

this command will serve the purpose of creating user who won't get an interactive shell.

**An interactive and non-interactive shell**

An interactive shell interacts with the user. If it's a login shell, any
commands in ~/.login are executed, if it's not a login shell (you can
spawn interactive subshells) .login is not evaluated.

A non-interactive shell does not interact with the user but works a
shell script. Whenever you invoke a shell script, the very first line
(the "shebang" #!/bin/bash) spawns a non-interactive subshell. All
non-interactive shells are no login shells, thus they do not evaluate
.login.

Any shell a user can log into is per definition an
interactive shell. If it wasn't (like /bin/false or /bin/nologon) the
user couldn't log in.